# How to remove some part of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, removechild

My code:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="div1">Keep this div</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <p>4</p>  
    <a href="">Keep this hyperlink</a>
</div>

<button id="button">Clear</button>
```

How can I remove everything after div with id div1 but keep the hyperlink when click the button which finally look like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="div1">Keep this div</div>
    <a href="">Keep this hyperlink</a>
</div>

<button id="button">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method along with [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#div1").nextAll(':not(:last-child)').remove();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9TZ2X/)**

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using jQuery so a `nextAll(':not(a)')` should work fine.

[**Working Demo**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/6li3mpyu).